# The number of Hamiltonian cycles in the complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I know that in the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ , there is $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$ or $n!(n-1)!$ Hamilton cycles. [wiki](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=The_number_of_Hamiltonian_cycles_in_the_complete_bipartite_graph) says first, [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBipartiteGraph.html) says the second one. I know that there is $2n$ ways to specify the "start", but why it goes like $n!(n-1)!$ ?

Comment: Consider small examples like $K_{3,3}$ and count for yourself.

Comment: Whether you divide by $2$ or not depends on whether you consider a cycle to be the same if you reverse its direction.

Answer (score 4):

As the graph is the complete bipartite graph, we can count the number of cycle as :

1. Choose an initial set
2. On the first set, you have $n$ choices for the first vertex
3. On the second again $n$ choices
4. Then $n-1$ choices
5. and so on $\ldots$

Therefore we count $H=2(n!)(n!)$ Hamiltonian cycles. However, we count each cycles $2n$ times because for any cycle there are $2n$ possibles vertices acting as "start". therefore we have $$H = \frac{2(n!)^2}{2n}=n!(n-1)!$$

Now, if you consider a cycle and its reverse as the same cycle, we you should divide this result by 2.