# Counting Hamiltonian cycles in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

**Given a graph $G = (W \cup U, E)$ where $W = \{w_1, w_2, ..., w_n\}$, $U = \{u_1, u_2, ..., u_n\}$ and $E = \{\{w_i, u_j\}: 1 \leq i, j \leq n\}$. The task is to calculate the number of Hamiltonian cycles in the graph G.**

The way I tried solving was,

Our vertex set $V = \{w_1, w_2 ... w_n, u_1, u_2, ... u_n\}$

Since we know 2 vertices $w_i \in W \text{ and } u_j \in U$ are adjacent if $1 \leq i, u \leq n$, this makes every vertex in W adjacent to every vertex in U giving us a bipartite graph. Also by Dirac's theorem
$deg(v) \leq \frac{|V|}{2}$ for a graph to be Hamiltonian.

So the task at hand condenses down to finding the number of hamiltonian cycles in a complete bipartite graph with n and n vertices i.e. $K_{n,n}$. Which is $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$, taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549694/the-number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-the-complete-bipartite-graph).

Is this the right way to solve this problem or am i missing something?

Comment: What do you mean "right way to solve this problem"? The graph defined above is $K_{n, n}$, so finding the number of Hamiltonian cycles in $K_{n, n}$ solves the problem. Whether you consider the linked question a sufficient solution is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since we know 2 vertices $w_i \in W \text{ and } u_j \in U$ are adjacent if $1 \leq i, u \leq n$, this makes every vertex in W adjacent to every vertex in U giving us a bipartite graph.

The correct statement here would be:

1. Since every edge is between a vertex in $W$ and a vertex in $U$, we have a bipartite graph. (The line I quoted from your proof doesn't say anything about edges in $W \times W$ or $U \times U$. Their non-existence is the crucial point).
2. Since the edge set is the full Cartesian product $W \times U$, we have a *complete* bipartite graph.

> So the task at hand condenses down to finding the number of
>   hamiltonian cycles in a complete bipartite graph with n and n vertices
>   i.e. $K_{n,n}$.

Correct.

> Which is $\frac{n!(n-1)!}{2}$, taken from here.

Yes, but the main point of the exercise is probably to show *why* that's the correct result.