# Determine the number of Hamiltonian cycles in K2,3 and K4,4 and the existence of Euler trails

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

1. Determine whether there exist Euler trails in the following graphs
2. Determine the number of Hamiltonian cycles in K2,3 and K4,4
   [image: Graph 1]

My approach:

A1. After observing graph 1, 8 vertices (boundary) have odd degrees.

It is contradictory to the definition (exactly 2 vertices must have odd degree).

In graph 2, there exists euler trails because exactly 2 vertices (top left- outer region and top right- outer region) have odd degrees.

A2. Hamiltonian cycle: contains every vertex one and only one time or proving by Dirac's theorem.

Following the Dirac's theorem:

*For K2,3*, number of vertices, n= 5, n/2= 2.5

For 2 vertices, deg (v)= 3; for the other 3 vertices, deg (v) = 2 **(which is less than 2.5)**

To satisfy Dirac's condition, for every vertex, v, deg (v)>=n/2. 
Hence, no hamiltonian cycle.

*For K4,4*, number of vertices, n=8, n/2 =4
For all the veritces, deg (v)= 4;

Hence, hamiltonian cycle exists.

But I am not sure how to find the total number of hamiltonian cycles.

Comment: Be careful, Dirac's theorem give you a *sufficient* condition to get Hamiltonian cycle, but this is not an equivalence. For example any cycle $C_n$ with $n\geq 3$ has minimum degree 2, hence does not verify Dirac's condition. However $C_n$ is trivially Hamiltonian.

Comment: For the last problem, draw a few Hamilton circuits for $K_{4,4}$ and you should quickly get a sense for what you need to count.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Sorry, still unable to solve. Can you please give me more hint? Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewDaly Should I use this formula ((n-1)! /2) here?
For $K_{2,3}$, number of hamiltonian cycle = (5-1)! /2 

Is it the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

For $K_{4,4}$ you can refer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549694/the-number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-the-complete-bipartite-graph).

For $K_{2,3}$, Suppose that you have an Hamiltonian cycle $(v_1v_2v_3v_4v_5)$.

Your graph is composed of two independent set of vertices $A$ and $B$, with $\vert A\vert=3$ and $\vert B\vert = 2$. Without loss of generality, we can suppose that $v_1\in A$ (otherwise look at the the cycle $(v_2v_3v_4v_5v_1)$).

Then 
$$v_1\in A \Rightarrow v_2\in B \Rightarrow v_3\in A \Rightarrow v_4\in B \Rightarrow v_5\in A \Rightarrow v_1\in B $$
Hence a contradiction. In general, for any $n\neq m$, $K_{n,m}$ is not Hamiltonian (but Dirac's theorem is not a proof)